# Spring, AppEngine : Add postgresql url in datasource for AppEngine

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, google-app-engine

I am working on a Spring-MVC application. I am trying out Google AppEngine and want to deploy a sample application on the server. I am using apache commons BasicDataSource where I need to provide the URL for PostgreSQL to connect. From the documentation I read, they are creating a seperate XML file and adding information there. But as I use the dataSource class for Hibernate and other annotations, how can I make the app work with Google AppEngine.

root-context.xml :

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
            destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <beans:property name="url"
                    value="WHAT_SHOULD_I_ADD_HERE"/>
    <beans:property name="username" value="USERNAME"/>
    <beans:property name="password" value="PASSWORD"/>
    <beans:property name="removeAbandoned" value="true"/>
    <beans:property name="removeAbandonedTimeout" value="20"/>
    <beans:property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false"/>
</beans:bean>

<!-- Hibernate 4 SessionFactory Bean definition -->
<beans:bean id="hibernate4AnnotatedSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <beans:property name="packagesToScan" value="com.myapp.spring.model" />

    <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
        <beans:props>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">false</beans:prop>
            <beans:prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</beans:prop>
        </beans:props>
    </beans:property>
</beans:bean>
```

Thank you.